# How to show different header and footer based on different components in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.js and i am having a problem in routing the components.
I have 2 different blogs and both blogs have different header and footer.
What is the best way to to render different header and footer for certain pages like Article and Home Screen.
I have tried making separate layouts and use Routing in those layouts and then used it in my App.js but it's not working

I have done the following things but nothing working for me:

My Simple_Blog.js file is:

```
class Simple_Blog extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
  
    <>
     
      <SimpleHeader />

      <Routes> 
          <Route exact path="/" element={<LaunchScreen/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/article1" element={<Article1/>}/>
      </Routes>

      <SimpleFooter />  
    
    </>
  );
  }
}
export default Simple_Blog
```

My Mega_Blog.js file is:

```
class Mega_Blog extends Component {
  render() {
  
   return (
  
    <>
     
      <MegaHeader />
      
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/mega" element={<Index/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/mega/series" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/mega/article-whats-new" element={<Article_New/>}/>
      </Routes> 

      <MegaFooter />  
    
    </>
  );
  }
}
export default Mega_Blog
```

My App.js file in which I have used these both layouts based on different paths:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
  
   return ( 
    <>
      <Router >

        <Routes>

          <Route exact path="/" element={ <Simple_Blog />} />       
          <Route exact path="/mega" element={ <Mega_Blog/> } >      
       
       </Routes>
  
     </Router>
        
    </>
  );
  }
}
export default App
```

Can anyone please find any mistake in it or tell me some other way to do this.

Comment: You are using the `exact` keyword for your routes. That means that if the url is even one letter off, it isn't a match. So if you want this to work, you have to remove that keyword from the routes in your App component (and change the order of the routes, so that the more specific route has priority over the more generic route).

Comment: I have tried this. it's just showing me only path="/" with the correct header and footer I want but when I move to path="/article1" it gives me a blank page and shows error in the console that <No routes matched location "/article1">
Same when I move to path='/mega' its just showing me blank pages

Comment: That is because `exact path="/"` takes precedence over `exact path="/article1"`. That's why you need to change the order of those routes, so that `exact path="/article1"` is checked before `exact path="/"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this in your App.js:

```
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/mega" element={<Mega_Blog/>}>
        <Route path="/series" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/article-whats-new" element={<Article_New/>}/>
        <Route path="/" element={<Index/>}>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/simple" element={<Simple_Blog/>}>
        <Route path="/article1" element={<Article1/>}/>
        <Route path="/" element={<LaunchScreen/>}/>
      </Route>
   </Routes>
 </Router>
```

And then modify your Mega_Blog and Simple_Blog components so that they just contain the header, the footer and an `<Outlet/>` tag (for the content of the page, e.g. Article1 or LaunchScreen). For example:

```
<>
  <MegaHeader />
  <Outlet />
  <MegaFooter />
</>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. there was a little mistake in it. which I corrected it like this:

 <Route path="/" element={<Simple_Blog/>}>
          <Route path="/article1" element={<Article1/>}/>
          <Route path="/" element={<LaunchScreen/>}/>
        </Route>

        <Route path="/mega" element={<Mega_Blog/>}>
           <Route path="/mega" element={<Index/>}/>
           <Route path="article-whats-new" element={<Article_New/>}/>
           <Route path="series" element={<Home/>}/>
        </Route>
   </Routes>

Comment: Just want to share this as well. Learned new thing i.e Outlet as used in the solution.
Hopes this might help someone else in the future: https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#nested-routes-and-layouts

Answer (score 1):

In your header component use `useLocation` from react-router-dom. Then depending on the route, you can render different header

Comment: okay I'll try this

Answer (score 1):

use useLocation in header component and get current route and on the base of route change your header and footer.

```
import {
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

let location = useLocation();

console.log(location)
```

Comment: okay I'll try this

Comment: I've tried this and when i use the use location hook the header stays the same

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better design some of your components separately for each route like the header and footer.

i.e if it is Mega_Blog
then

```js
    const Mega_Blog=()=>{
    return (
    <Mega_Blogs_Header />
    <Mega_Blog_Contents />
    <Mega_Blog_Footer />
    
    );
    
    }
    export default Mega_Blog;
```

Do the same thing for other routes.

Comment: won't it affect the performance of my website using the same header and footer multiple times for every page?

Comment: That's what React is about, It's all about re-using components.
All the components are re-useable in React.